# Duplo clique na linha de um DataGridView transporta os dados para um formulário

Tags: c#, winforms

Bom dia a todos.

Seguinte pessoal, tenho um formulário de (consulta) que contém o DataGrideView. E o formulário de cadastro em outro formulário.

Gostaria de entender, como posso ao dar duplo clique em uma linha do DataGrideView ele enviar todos os dados da linha para este formulário de cadastro (para eu poder fazer o crud de alterar).

Imagem para exemplificar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Classe datagrid**

```
 class datagride
{
    banco conexao = new banco();

    // Atributos

    private string nomeTabela;
    private DataGridView nomeDataGride;

    // Construtor

    public datagride(string pnt, DataGridView pndg)
    {
        nomeTabela = pnt;
        nomeDataGride = pndg;
    }

    public datagride(DataGridView pndg)
    {
        nomeDataGride = pndg;
    }


    // Método

    public DataGridView carregarGride(string sql = "")
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //Nova tabela

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();

        if (sql == "")
        {
            sql = "select * from " + nomeTabela;
        }

        da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, conexao.conecta());
        da.Fill(dt);

        nomeDataGride.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;

        conexao.desconecta();
        return nomeDataGride;
    }
```

**Construtor **

```
public cliente(cliente c, string pn, string pe, int pt, string pem, string ps, int pcod)
    {
        nome = pn;
        endereco = pe;
        telefone = pt;
        email = pem;
        sexo = ps;
        cod = pcod;
    }
```

**Instância no form**

```
 private void btnAtualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtCodC.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Digite o código do cliente");
            txtCodC.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                cliente cli = new cliente(txtNomeCliente.Text, txtEnderecoCliente.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtTelefoneCliente.Text), txtEmailCliente.Text, cmbSexoCliente.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtCodC.Text));
                cli.AlterarCliente();
                MessageBox.Show("Alterado com sucesso!");

            }
            catch (Exception ex) // Caso de erro, irá mostrar a mensagem de erro!
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); // mensagem de erro
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Cara, esse print tá horrível :p

Comment: Tentei melhorar @jbueno :)

Comment: Tá bem melhor. Estou escrevendo uma resposta. Me ajudaria muito se você colocasse o código que usas para popular o DataGrid

Comment: Pronto, já atualizei @jbueno

Comment: Dê uma olhada na minha resposta. Tentei ser o mais genérico possível, pois sem conhecer seu modelo fica bem complicado.

Answer (score 5):

Existem diversas maneiras de fazer isso. Depende muito da sua preferência/necessidade e alguns outros fatores como o `DataSource` do `DataGridView`.

Primeiramente, o seu `Form` de editar cliente tem que poder receber um parâmetro do tipo `Cliente` no seu construtor. Assim, você só precisa se dar o trabalho de instanciar um objeto `Cliente`, mandar para o `Form` e dentro do `Form` você define quais campos vais mostrar, etc. Vamos assumir que o `Form` se chame `FormEditarCliente`. O construtor ficaria assim:

```
public FormEditarCliente(Cliente c){ ... }
```

Vou te mostrar duas maneiras que você pode fazer isso

**A primeira** (e a que eu mais uso) só funciona quando a seu `DataGridView` é populado por um `List<T>`. Supondo que `List<Cliente> _clientes` é a fonte de dados do seu grid.

O evento `CellDoubleClick` ficaria assim:

```
public static void dataGrid_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     int idCliente = Convert.ToInt32(dataGrid["nomeDaColunaId", e.RowIndex].Value);
     var cliente = _clientes.Single(x => x.Id == idCliente);

     var form = new FormEditarCliente(cliente);
     form.ShowDialog();
}
```

O que é feito ali em cima é bem simples. A primeira linha pega o Id do cliente que está no `DataGridView` (suponho que os registros tenham um Id e que esse Id seja uma **chave primária**), depois é feita uma consulta na lista que serve como fonte de dados do `DataGridView`. Essa consulta consiste em buscar um registro em que o Id seja igual ao Id que foi capturado do `DataGridView`. Então é chamado o `Form` passando por parâmetro o  cliente que foi selecionado com `Single()`.

**A segunda** (e a que eu usaria no seu caso depois de ver a edição) consiste em apenas pegar o Id do cliente que está no `DataGridView` e depois disso buscar este cliente no banco de dados. Depois passá-lo por parâmetro para o `Form` de edição, exatamente como foi feito antes.

```
public static void dataGrid_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     int idCliente = Convert.ToInt32(dataGrid["nomeDaColunaId", e.RowIndex].Value);
     Cliente cliente = BuscarClientePorId(idCliente);

     var form = new FormEditarCliente(cliente);
     form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Da uma olhada no código do meu construtor do alterar e a instancia no form, fiquei um pouco perdido nessa parte

Comment: Perdido no que? Tem alguma dúvida?

Comment: Então, vamos por partes... Você pode entrar no chat?

Comment: Sim, eu passei o parâmetro (cliente c) porém qnd faço a instância no form o que vou passar dentro?

Comment: Posso sim @jbueno

Answer (score 1):

Considero por o dataGrid e os botões de edição e os métodos no mesmo formulário. Assim quando ocorrer um Insert, Update ou Delete, é chamar o método Select para carregar novamente o dataGrid.

Answer (score 1):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom você pode usar o evento CellContentDoubleClick do DatagridView,
no click você pega o index da linha pela Célula clicada:

dtClientesDtgv é o name do meu Datagrid.

```
var pegarIndex = dtClientesDtgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
```

E então você pode pegar os valores da linha através do Index encontrado no Click:

```
var pegarId = dtClientesDtgv.Rows[pegarIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

A partir daqui é só passar os valores de cada célula para suas variáveis.